# Trying to pass login credentials through HTTP, need workaround

Tags: php, http, post, get, iot

To My Web Developing Friends:

I just recently bought a GoGoGate2 Garage Door Opener, and I am attempting to set up a local workaround via HTTP request for firing the open event of the Garage Door Opener. (This is for use with an IoT hub). I tapped into my GoGoGate2 via IP and it brought me to a browser based UI. I used WireShark to sniff out HTTP requests that were firing on the open event. I came to the conclusion that the door could be open and closed via the following HTTP request.

**OPENS DOOR:**
http://device-ip/isg/opendoor.php?numdoor=1&status=2

**CLOSES DOOR:**
http://device-ip/isg/opendoor.php?numdoor=1&status=0

Okay that was simple enough. When I fire the HTTP request from a computer or phone on my network, the request works and the door opens and closes perfectly. However, when I attempt to fire the HTTP request from my Hubitat, the event is not firing. I attempted to use my HTTP exactly as written from an incognito window in chrome and I received a message "Restricted Access". So apparently the Hubitat needs some sort of authentication to speak to the GoGoGate2 device.

Is there some way I can tap into my Hubitat and use it to connect to my GoGoGate2 and have it save the login credentials? That's how I did it from my phone/computer. Is there no way to do this exact same thing from the Hubitat itself?

Sorry if this is a noob question.

Please note I have also tried using the format `login:password@device-ip/isg/opendoor.php?numdoor=1&status=2`with no success

Also, not sure if this is of assistance, but during the authentication process on the Garage Door Opener, the login is performed by performing a post method. From what I have sniffed out, this is the relevant information.

```
Request Method: POST
Request URI : /index.php/index.php
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n

Form Item: "login" = "mylogin"
Key: login
Value: mylogin

Form Item: "pass" = "mypass"
Key: pass
Value: mypass

Form Item: "sesion-abierta" = "1"
Key: sesion-abierta
Value: 1

Form Item: "send-login" = "Sign In"
Key: send-login
Value: Sign In
```

I am unsure how to pass post information in via HTTP request, if anyone has some insight on how to do this, or a work around?

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use cURL for this request:

curl -d "login=mylogin&pass=mypass&sesion-abierta=1&send-login=Sign In" -X POST http://www.requestdomain.com

find more information at https://ec.haxx.se/http-post.html

Comment: Okay but how would I utiilize this to build a script that I can run on a computer that I have acting as a server? Can I run a localized php server?

Answer (score 0):

Since the login is form-based, it seems likely the credentials are stored as cookies. If these cookies are long-lived, then you might be able to re-use them when connecting to the API. Is it possible to specify cookies in the HTTP request? Otherwise, is it possible to execute a sequence of multiple requests from the device - a POST to authenticate then the operation.

Alternatively, you could host your own proxy on the local network that performs the login and the subsequent request internally. This can be done with programmatically with curl in PHP. Here's an example: http://blog.andyhunt.info/2011/12/21/using-php-and-curl-to-log-in-to-a-website/

Make sure to use the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR option to store the authentication cookies from the login form so they can be included in subsequent requests.

Comment: I attempted to pass through the info for post in http request but was unsuccessful. If you have any insight into the syntax for such an operation it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps use PHP curl to programmatically submit the login form and then request the second page?